# Testing a chained promise using Jasmine without returning the promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, promise, jasmine

I've been adding test coverage to existing code, and have come across a pattern a few times recently that I've had difficulty testing.

Given some existing method like:

```js
public foo(): void {
    SomeResource.get().then((someResource) => {
        someOtherMethod(someResource);
    });
}
```

And I'll need to test that someOtherMethod gets called with a correct param. Naively, I'd do something like:

```js
it("gets called", () => {
    spyOn(SomeResource, "get").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(someTestValue));
    spyOn(someOtherMethod);
    foo();
    expect(someOtherMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someTestValue);
});
```

But from what I understand, because someOtherMethod is downstream of something async (even mocked) I'm not guaranteed that it'll get called by the time my spec reaches it's expect--I'll have a flakey test.

What I've been doing instead is modifying the method-under-test a bit to return the promise:

```js
public foo(): Promise(void) {
    return SomeResource.get().then((someResource) => {
        someOtherMethod(someResource);
    });
}
```

which then allows me to test it like this:

```js
it("gets called", (done) => {
    spyOn(SomeResource, "get").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(someTestValue));
    spyOn(someOtherMethod);
    foo().then(() => {
        expect(someOtherMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someTestValue);
        done();
    })
});
```

But I've got two issues there:

1. It doesn't feel great modifying the method-under-test (and it's signature!) for the sole benefit of my tests
2. Sometimes it's not possible to return the promise chain

Is there a better way to test chained promises with Jasmine? A way that doesn't require the function to return the promise for me to wait on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
it("gets called", async done => {
    spyOn(SomeResource, "get").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(someTestValue));
    spyOn(someOtherMethod);
    // call foo
    foo();
    // before going to your assertion, ensure the pending promise has resolved
    await SomeResource.get();
    // ok, pending promise has resolved, carry on with the assertion
    expect(someOtherMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someTestValue);
    done();
});
```